# Как использовать уже готовую базу данных с flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

Дело в том что миграции для БД были сделаны с помощью `php Laravel`. Хотелось бы иметь модели для `ORM flask-sqlalchemy`. Как это сделать? Всё переносить вручную?

Как использовать уже готовую базу данных с flask-sqlalchemy?

Comment: mysql, postgresql, mongodb, sqlite ? какая db?

Comment: @Victor VosMottor thanks Monica mysql

Comment: примите ответ если он вам помог — галочка слева от ответа

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install flask_sqlalchemy
```

```
# ...
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://username:password@host/database'
# ...
```